# setBackgroundDrawable in android

Tags: android, view, drawable, imagebutton

I want to set background *drawable* of a imagebutton. There are two methods for this (as far as I see): setBackground and `setBackgroundDrawable`. I am using `setBackground`, it says it has been added in API level 16 but my project's **`min SDK version is 7`**. For this i am using setBackgroundDrawable, but its is not changing the drawable at run time in api lower then 16?This is my code snippet

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

private void setVariable() {
        try {

        //change the bg for save button
        int sdk = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        if(sdk < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        //register.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_save));
                register.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btnsave));
            }else{
                register.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_save));
            }
            //register.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_save));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
    }
}
```

What am I supposed to use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `register.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_save);`.

`public void setBackgroundResource (int resid)` is available from API Level 1.

Answer (score 1):

You  are mistaking while writing resource id of drawable.
You're using ***R.id.btnsave*** instead of ***'R.drawable.btn_save'***

Otherwise, your code is absolutely right!

Comment: Yes i have figure it out ...i have done the mistake but register.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_save);  is working for me...

Answer (score 1):

try the following :

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.new_todo_image);
```

and give some feedback

Hope that helps .

Comment: Yes its working but dont know why  register.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btnsave)); is not working ...

Comment: i dont know why you changed your mind about accepting my answer